# RabbitMQ streams with Golang client - Failed to create producer: dial tcp: missing address

Tags: go, rabbitmq, rabbitmq-stream

Here is my rabbit server config with docker-compose:

services:

```
  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:3-management
    container_name: "vibe-rabbitmq"
    volumes:
      - rabbitmq_data:/var/lib/rabbitmq
    ports:
      - "5672:5672"
      - "15672:15672"
      - "5552:5552"
    environment:
      - RABBITMQ_PLUGINS=rabbitmq_stream,rabbitmq_stream_management
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=rabbitmq
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=rabbitmq
```

Here is my golang code

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-stream-go-client/pkg/amqp"
    "github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-stream-go-client/pkg/stream"
    "log"
    "time"
)

func main() {

    streamName := "your_stream_name"

    env, err := stream.NewEnvironment(
        stream.NewEnvironmentOptions().
            SetHost("0.0.0.0").
            SetPort(5552). // 5552
            SetUser("rabbitmq").
            SetPassword("rabbitmq"),
    )

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to create environment: %s", err)
    }

    err = env.DeclareStream(streamName, &stream.StreamOptions{})

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to declare stream: %v", err)
    }

    log.Printf("Stream '%s' created successfully", streamName)

    producer, err := env.NewProducer(streamName, &stream.ProducerOptions{})
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to create producer: %s", err)
    }

}
```

I run the above, and I get this error:

```
2023/12/14 18:15:17 Stream 'your_stream_name' created successfully
2023/12/14 18:15:17 Failed to create producer: dial tcp: missing address
exit status 1
```

what's very strange is I can create the stream using the env instance, but cannot create the producer?

Answer (score 2):

Please read the overview [about stream](https://blog.rabbitmq.com/posts/2021/07/connecting-to-streams/)

The client must be able to look up the node where it is connected.
The reason why you can create the stream is because it uses a different connection. Called locator.

When you ask for a producer, the client queries the stream to understand where is the leader after that tries to connect to the node leader.

Possible solutions:

1. Use localhost instead of `0.0.0.0`
2. Use the [advertised_host and port](https://blog.rabbitmq.com/posts/2021/07/connecting-to-streams/#advertised-host-and-port)

TO use Docker see the [documentation](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-stream-go-client?tab=readme-ov-file#run-server-with-docker)

```
docker run -it --rm --name rabbitmq -p 5552:5552 -p 15672:15672\
    -e RABBITMQ_SERVER_ADDITIONAL_ERL_ARGS='-rabbitmq_stream advertised_host localhost -rabbit loopback_users "none"' \
    rabbitmq:3-management
```

then:

```
docker exec rabbitmq rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_stream_management
```

Comment: I clicked both links - not obvious what's wrong - is there another port that needs to be open?

Comment: The port is `5552`. You need to check if the client can lookup the DNS server name.  p.s. I am the author of that client you can find me on discord, see : https://blog.rabbitmq.com/posts/2023/04/announcing-rabbitmq-community-discord-server/

Comment: I updated OP, already been using 5552

Comment: thanks, I changed to localhost, docker-compose in OP has 5552, and the "2023/12/15 17:32:02 Failed to create producer: dial tcp: missing address" error is really bizarre

Comment: if you use docker you need to set `advertised_host`. I updated the answer. You are missing the `RABBITMQ_SERVER_ADDITIONAL_ERL_ARGS` env to set the host